# Events of TIdFTPServer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

when i am trying to write code in `OnListDirectory` Event for `IdFTPServer1` the compiler says this :

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(18): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TIdFTPListOutput'
```

it seems that `ADirectoryListing` as `TIdFTPListOutput` is an Undeclared identifier in `OnListDirectory` Event procedure also there is the same problem in the other event functions of this indy. how can i solve it?

```
procedure TForm1.IdFTPServer1ListDirectory(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const APath: string; ADirectoryListing: TIdFTPListOutput; const ACmd,
  ASwitches: string);
begin

end;
```

thanx for helping

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `IdFTPListOutput` unit to your `uses` clause.